# Having problem in using wordpress with an other language

Tags: multi-language, localization, language

I am using Persian Wordpress  but I have a problem. when I want to publish a new post in Persian , I get all Persian letters alternated with question mark -"?" -.
My wp-config.php file set the database charset to utf-8 .I installed Persian language to my Wordpress but it didn't fix my problem.
you can see my full problem in [chergheshab.ir](http://cheragheshab.ir) . 
I also tried to change my collation from phpMyAdmin to utf8_general_ci but it didn't work .
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have all your databases utf8_general_ci if you're website uses other than just Latin characters. Can you have a look at your database tables? If you can then have a look at the `wp_posts` table and see if they are `????` or actual characters. Otherwise your posts are saved wrong in the DB which why they are appearing unreadable in your blog.

If they do not have utf8_general_ci unicoding try to:

- Either create a new database with utf8_general_ci Unicode or try to convert your current DB. [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) about converting a database. BACKUP if you need to!
- Install a clean WordPress via FTP
- Make sure your config.php has these settings (which are the default):

  ```
  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
  define('DB_COLLATE', '');
  ```
- After installation make sure all your tables are utf8 general_ci (if you can access your database?)
- Make sure your theme's index.php is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Give it a try and let me know if this changed anything?

Comment: About last item "Make sure your theme's index.php is saved with UTF-8 encoding. ", how can I check it ?

Comment: Open your index.php file with your code editor and choose **File --> Save with encoding** (depending on the editor) and then choose UTF-8. And then just upload the index.php file to your themes folder.